# How to erase a stroke in photoshop upon touch by an eraser tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Having drawn a line x strokes ago (with brush tool), I want to delete it by moving a tool over it, how do I do that?

The typical eraser just erases a part of it.

Comment: Brush tool in Photoshop produces pixels: as soon as you let go your pen you're left with merged mass of points (unlike brushes in Illustrator that produce vectors that you can select at any point)

Comment: Try stroking it.

Comment: @Joonas What's does that mean?

Comment: Not really anything... — One _maybe_ helpful tip I could give is that if you make a new layer and draw 1 line on that layer, you can remove the line later by removing the layer without affecting anything that is behind (or in front of) it on another layer. And if you save it as .psd, you can come back to edit it. You always want to have `.psd` file as a back-up, even if the target format is like `.png` or something.

Comment: You can kind of do this with the history brush and the history panel. [See tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TA5FvZgXsU&feature=emb_logo).

Comment: @BillyKerr Wait, so it **acutally** is possible? I haven't looked that much into the history brush. But if it is possible, then I just accepted a wrong answer that says it's not.

Comment: Well, kind of, but not how you described it working. So, the answer is correct technically. However, you can paint out a brush stroke you made, by selecting a history state to paint back to.

Comment: I've added this as an answer now, in case it's something you might find useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You can't.

Photoshop is a pixel-based application. It stores images by storing the respective colour of each of the image's pixels, and no (or very little) other data.

That means that every brush stroke you make directly affects pixels, and is stored in Photoshop only as pixels. Photoshop doesn't see a brush stroke as a single object, it's just an operation that changed the colour of some pixels.

Hence, as soon as you painted over one stroke with another, the only ways you have to remove the first stroke is your undo states (if present and they go that far back) or a meticulous and time-consuming pixel-based retouching operation.

The functionality you are looking for is object-based painting, where every brush stroke is its own object. This is, theoretically, possible in Adobe Illustrator. Illustrator is an object-oriented application, and there you can edit and re-edit every object you create at a later time. Painting in Illustrator is disrecommended, though. It is possible, but you will need a very heavy rig to be able to compute every of your (tens of?) thousands of brush strokes independently. Also, it is... hard. Object-oriented drawing is not really fit for what painting requires.

My advice would be to *live with your mistakes*. It's what offline painters do and have done for centuries. Paint over it. Subtly erase it. Work around it. Be inspired by it. If you can't hide it, flaunt it.

What you *can* do, is have one of Photoshop's strengths work for you: work in layers. Don't put every brush stroke on a single layer, but collect clusters in their own layers, and group those layers to form objects. That way, retroactive correction is a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

The way you describe this is not possible in Photoshop.  However there is a possible work around which might work in some very specific cases.

You can use the History Brush, and the History Panel to paint out a stroke you previously made at an earlier point.

Here's an example below. I painted three strokes using the Paint Brush tool (a number one, two and three).  Everything here is painted directly onto the background layer. The one and two overlap, and the three is separate.  You can select the first Brush Tool history state to paint back to, then choose the History brush and paint out the second stroke you made, by essentially painting back to the first paint brush state.

[image]

Comment: +1. Great option and something I had not considered in my answer, a I hardly ever use it. As far as I know, though, the History Brush depends on having a, well, history, and becomes unable to achieve what.you want as soon as the history state is gone. Either because it's too old or you saved and opened the file.

Comment: @Vincent - yes, saving and exiting the document would erase the history and is one limitation. As I said, it would only work in very specific cases, like the one shown.